# How would I rearrange the equation $S = ut + \frac 12 at^2$ to make $t$ the subject of the equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics, classical-mechanics

How would I rearrange the equation $S = ut + \frac 12 at^2$ to make t the subject of the equation ?

I'm not sure whether I should times the left side by $2$ or minus $\frac 12$ from the left side.

Comment: This is a quadratic equation in $t$. Use the quadratic formula to find $t$ in terms of $S,u,a$.

Comment: I don't quite understand could you please elaborate. Thanks.

Comment: What do you call "make the subject of" ??? Your two proposals $2S=RHS$ or $S-1/2=RHS$ are meaningless.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I rearrange second equation of motion to find t?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2091671/how-can-i-rearrange-second-equation-of-motion-to-find-t)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $s=ut+\frac{1}{2}at^2$

Re-write
\begin{align}
t^{2}+\frac{2u}{a}t-\frac{2s}{a}=0
\end{align}
Thus,
\begin{align}
t &= \frac{-\frac{2u}{a} \pm \sqrt{\frac{4u^{2}}{a^{2}}+\frac{8s}{a}}}{2}\\
  &= -\frac{u}{a} \pm \sqrt{\frac{u^{2}}{a^{2}}+\frac{2s}{a}}
\end{align}

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be $(u^2/a^2)+2(s/a)$ inside the root?

Comment: @blackpen Yes, you are right. It's amazing how many typos I have for this answer. I must be tired...many thanks for your correction.

Comment: @lhf Fair comment, consider it done!

Comment: you are welcome. Somebody else helped correct my own formula just 12 hours ago, in another post :)

Answer (score 2):

The quadratic solution is obvious as shown in earlier solutions posted here. What is important to note is that in for the standard case, time is positive hence $t>0$, i.e. we can only take the positive root, i.e. 
$$t=\frac {-u+\sqrt{u^2+2aS}}a$$

Comment: @BarryCipra - Thanks. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

This is a quadratic in $t$. Meaning you should use the quadratic formula.

Moving the "$S$" constant to the right, we get $\frac 12 at^2+ut-S=0$ And multiplying by $2$, we get$$at^2+2ut-2S=0$$

Solving for $t$, we get $$t=\frac {-2u\pm\sqrt{4u^2-4(-2S)(a)}}{2a}=\frac {-2u\pm\sqrt{4u^2+8aS}}{2a}=\frac {-u\pm\sqrt{u^2+2aS}}{a}$$

Answer (score 1):

To be hyperprecise, the answer is

$$t=
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle{-u\pm\sqrt{u^2+2aS}\over a}&\text{if }a\not=0\\
\displaystyle{S\over u}&\text{if }a=0\text{ and } u\not=0\\
\end{cases}$$

If $a=u=0$ the equation becomes $S=0$, which is either true for *all* $t$ or for *no* $t$, depending on the value of $S$.