# How can I rearrange second equation of motion to find t?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, classical-mechanics

The equation is:
$S = ut+ \frac{at^2}{2}$

Answer (score 2):

HINT: $$s=ut+\frac{1}{2}at^2$$ $$\implies at^2+2ut-2s=0$$ $$\implies t=\frac{-2u\pm\sqrt{4u^2+8as}}{2a}$$ $$\implies t=\frac{-u\pm\sqrt{u^2+2as}}{a}$$

Leave the negative one, as in classical macehenics, time does not assume negative value.

Answer (score 1):

Write
$$s=ut+\frac{1}{2}at^{2}$$
Thus
$$0=at^{2}+2ut-2s$$
Assume $a \neq 0$, whence
$$0=t^2+\left(\frac{2u}{a}\right)t-2\left(\frac{s}{a}\right)$$
Complete the square on the terms in $t$
$$0=\left(t+\frac{u}{a} \right)^{2}-\frac{u^{2}}{a^{2}}-\frac{2s}{a}$$
hence
$$\left( t+\frac{u}{a}\right)^{2}=\frac{1}{a^{2}}\left(u^{2}+2as \right)$$
From which
$$t+\frac{u}{a}=\pm \frac{1}{a}\sqrt{u^{2}+2as}$$
And thus
$$t=-\frac{u}{a}\pm \frac{1}{a}\sqrt{u^{2}+2as}$$
I'll leave it as an exercise as to whether both $\pm$ cases are required.