# Rearrange equation of motion for time

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics, classical-mechanics

One of the "SUVAT" equations of motions is:
$$s=ut+\frac{1}{2}at^2$$
Which relates distance, $s$, in meters, to initial velocity, $u$, in $\dfrac{m}{s}$, time elapsed, $t$, in seconds and acceleration, $a$, in $\dfrac{m}{s^2}$.

I have distance, acceleration and initial velocity, I'd like to calculate $t$.  I suspect this requires the use of calculus but I'm not versed with what question to ask search engines to find the right mathematical approach to solve for $t$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I rearrange second equation of motion to find t?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2091671/how-can-i-rearrange-second-equation-of-motion-to-find-t)

Comment: @huzaifaabedeen, thank you.  I think the question and answers are lower quality but yes they are about the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we write the equation in the form $$\frac{1}{2}at^2+ut-s=0$$ and assuming $a\ne 0$ using the quadratic formula $$x=\frac{-B\pm\sqrt{B^2-4AC}}{2A}$$ where `A`, `B` and `C` relate to $$Ax^2+Bx+C=0$$ we get $$A=\frac{1}{2}a$$ $$B=u$$ $$C=-s$$
$$t_{1,2}=\frac{-u\pm\sqrt{u^2+2as}}{a}$$

Comment: it's corrected, thank you for your hint

Comment: forgive but my concentration isn't well today

Comment: here in Leipzig the sun is shining and in a few minutes i will trink a cup of coffee

Comment: :)  Thanks!  I've got it.  Will correct your answer and let you enjoy your coffee :)  Shame someone downvoted your answer without leaving a comment or helping to correct it.